# Remove duplicates or distinction from array of objects by knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

How to remove duplicates objects from an array by using Knockout.js

```
   var ticketgroups = [
      {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
      {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
      {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
      {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
      {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
      {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
    ];
```

Output should be

```
 var filltered = [
          {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
          {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
          {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
        ];
```

How to bind on my views.

```
<select id="customticketgroup" data-bind="options: $root.filltered.TicketGroup"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SortOrder` is supposed to be a unique value, you can use it to filter out duplicates. The example below uses a `Map` to ensure there's only *one* value per sort order.

```js
function uniquesBy(getKey, xs) {
  return Array.from(
    new Map(
      xs.map(x => [getKey(x), x])
    ).values()
  )
}

const TicketGroup1 = "Ticket Group 1";
const TicketGroup2 = "Ticket Group 2";
const TicketGroup3 = "Ticket Group 3";

const ticketgroups = [
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
];

ko.applyBindings({ 
  filtered: uniquesBy(g => g.SortOrder, ticketgroups)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
  options: filtered,
  optionsText: 'TicketGroup'
"></select>
```

If your ticketgroups array is actually an `observableArray`, you can use a `pureComputed` for `filtered`. If you're only interested in the `TicketGroup` property after sorting, you could chain a `.map(g => g.TicketGroup)` to extract the values.

```js
function uniquesBy(getKey, xs) {
  return Array.from(
    new Map(
      xs.map(x => [getKey(x), x])
    ).values()
  )
}

const TicketGroup1 = "Ticket Group 1";
const TicketGroup2 = "Ticket Group 2";
const TicketGroup3 = "Ticket Group 3";

const ticketgroups = ko.observableArray([
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup1, SortOrder: 1},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup2, SortOrder: 2},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
  {TicketGroup: TicketGroup3, SortOrder: 3},
]);

ko.applyBindings({ 
  filtered: ko.pureComputed(() => 
    uniquesBy(g => g.SortOrder, ticketgroups())
      .map(g => g.TicketGroup)
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
  options: filtered
"></select>
```